# Pass array of variables to URL parmaters

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am using the following filter to set some argument for url with name= paramater of 'srtby_homepage'.

```
    $runorders = 'srtby_homepage';
    add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query/name='.$runorders, 'relationship_options_filter', 10, 3);
```

I am trying use an array of values in place of this like below but think iv gone wrong somewhere

```
    $runorders = array(
        'srtby_homepage',
        'srtby_featuredops',
    );
    add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query/name='.$runorders, 'relationship_options_filter', 10, 3);
```

Here is how I am currently doing things, 2 functions for different $runorders:

```
    $runorders = 'srtby_homepage';
    add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query/name='.$runorders, 'relationship_options_filter', 10, 3);

    function relationship_options_filter($options, $field, $the_post) {

      $options['post_status'] = array('publish');

      return $options;
    }

    $runorders = 'srtby_featuredops';
    add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query/name='.$runorders, 'relationship_options_filter_2', 10, 3);

    function relationship_options_filter_2($options, $field, $the_post) {

      $options['post_status'] = array('publish');

      return $options;
    };
```

Comment: are you using wrodpress?

Comment: what query are you trying to accomplish for the array?

Comment: its for an ACF relationship field, it runs an ajax request and pulls back a list of posts using the ur query 'acf/fields/relationship/query/name='.$runorders'. I need $runorders to display a single value out of that array

Answer (score 1):

You can send array by [] in the `GET` request Like `foo[]=bar&foo[]=bar2&...`

```
$runorders = array(
        'srtby_homepage',
        'srtby_featuredops',
    );
foreach($runorders as $key=>$value){
    $runorders[$key] = 'name[]='.urlencode($value);
}
$runorders = implode('&',$runorders);
    add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query/'.$runorders, 'relationship_options_filter', 10, 3);
```

OR if this String not a `Get` request! You can join array by a delimiter like `,`

by using `implode(',',$array);`  and read it by using `explode(',',$string);`

Comment: I do not know you have this code where  you use. but my solutions is standard and you can convert array to string or reverse it.

Comment: I also thought your solution would work, it makes sense. I have updated my question to show more code

Answer (score 0):

First of all made a query string with you options array using key to value and then concatenate this string with your URL

```
<?php 
$runorders = array(
      'key1' =>  'srtby_homepage',
      'key2' => 'srtby_featuredops',
    );
$query_string = ''; 
foreach($runorders as $key => $val)
{
    $query_string .= '&'.$key.'='.$val;
}
$url = 'www.example.com/page.php?'.$query_string;
?>
```